# Preventing image URL from showing when page is still waiting for remote image

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

Before the image finishes loading, it shows the URL of the image.

This looks really bad, esp when the user has a slower connection

Example: see the second image, which is still loading:

[image: example]

Comment: What browser and/or HTML markup is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove "Alt" and "title" attributes  of your `<img  tag`.
2. put image style, width and height equal to the final thumbnail that will load there.
   ( create CSS class for this preferably )

These 2 alterations will give a better user experience.

```
<img src="http://mysite/images/myimg.jpg" style='width:100px;height:100px;' />
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_IMG.asp - `alt` attribute is required. Whereas `title` attribute has nothing to do with the text displayed instead of the image. This text appearson mouse hover.

Answer (score 1):

That's the `alt` html attribute value.

```
<img src="http://yoursite/path/image.jpg" 
    alt="text to display when no image available"/>
```

simply put a blank string in the `alt` attribute.

That should be the easiest, javascript-free method of doing this.